# Разница в mysql и Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Использовал всегда `mysql` базу. Делал следующую операцию

```
@pics.update_all("views = views + 100, ctr = clicks/views")
```

Таким образом я апдейтил `views+100`, и ctr уже считался исходя из новых данных по `views`.

Сейчас перешел на PostgreSQL и он такой запрос уже не может выполнить. Пишет что на ноль делить нельзя. Т.е. он делит на `views` в котором старые данные, часто это ноль.

Это отличие между mysql и postgresql или моя ошибка где-то?

Comment: И то, и другое. Ваша ошибка в том, что вы делаете операцию, в которой теоретически присутствует деление на ноль.

Comment: ctr = clicks/(views + 100)

Comment: ctr=clicks/(views+100) - я так и сделал. вопрос почему на mysql работает операция которую написал выше, а на постгресе нет

Comment: дело в том, что в PostgreSQL одна операция выполняется, как в нормальной СУБД - в один момент. MySQL же этого правила не придерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать обернуть "views" в такую конструкцию

```
clicks/(coalesce(nullif(views,0),1))
```

Comment: Результат получится не тот, что надо - без прибавленного 100

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых базах можно написать, например, так:

```
_i = 0;

UPDATE table1
SET column_row_num = _i
  , _i = _i + 1;
```

Тут в колонку `column_row_num` кладётся значение из счётчика строк `_i` и одновременно он увеличивается. В `PostgreSQL` так нельзя: *справа от знака присваивания всегда пишутся старые значения переменных*. Если хотите, чтобы одно действие выполнялось строго после другого, - разбейте один `UPDATE` на два:

```
UPDATE table1
SET views = views + 100;

UPDATE table1
SET ctr = clicks / views;
```

А можно и сделать, как указал [norbornen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659/norbornen) -

```
UPDATE table1
SET views = views + 100
  , ctr = clicks / (views + 100);
```